# How to write formula to compare values in two columns in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, compare

Column A has Email domain value(ex: yahoo.com) and Column B has Description value (Ex:Yahoo User). So I need to compare the value if its matching or not. if A has gmail.com and B has Yahoo user the result should be 'false'. Can someone help withe the formula to place it on excel.

Comment: Show some test data with expected results, also whatever you have tried so far.

Comment: Does it always say "[email service] user"? It's a little tricky if you're trying to match *any word* in a cell with *any word* in another.  As @ManishChristian stated, could we see some sample data?  What have you tried so far?  The answers you have received so far won't work unless one is just `gmail` and you're trying to find it in say `gmail.com`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are comparing each cell in column B with its corresponding cell in column A, try this

```
=COUNTIF(B2,"*"&A2&"*")>0
```

Comment: I don't think this works for what OP is asking. If `A2` is `yahoo.com` and `B2` is `yahoo user`, it returns `FALSE`. (Same if you reverse the two)

Comment: This is what I read in the description - "So I need to compare the value if its matching or not. if A has gmail.com and B has Yahoo user the result should be 'false'."

Comment: Ah, I read that as saying that one column has `yahoo.com`, and the other has `yahoo user`.  It correctly returns false if one is `gmail.com` and the other `Yahoo user`, but (unless I'm just missing something), the formula still returns false if one is `yahoo.com` and the other is `yahoo user`.

Comment: Assume A2=yahoo.com and B2=abc@yahoo.com, the formula will return True. Isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, that's right. I guess I just don't know how OP actually has the data, so was taking it literally as `yahoo user`. But I think you're right, it'll be an email address.

Comment: I suggested it as per the description but you are right, we still don't know the layout of the data.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the entry value will be like Yahoo User or yahoo.com where the domain name starts with the first character and can be delimited by `.` or (space character), here is my solution.

```
Column A    Column B
Yahoo.com   Gmail user
Gmail User  yahoo user
gamil.com   yahoo.com
```

In C1 enter this formula

```
=LEFT(B2,MIN(IFERROR(SEARCH(".",B2),9999999),IFERROR(SEARCH(" ",B2),9999999))-1) = LEFT(A2,MIN(IFERROR(SEARCH(".",A2),9999999),IFERROR(SEARCH
```

Here is a snapshot to make more clear.

[image]

It might seem like a complex formula, but it is quite simple. The formula extracts the domain name from left and then matches to see if they are identical. Please mark as answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of doing it:

It is possible to search for a string into a cell with the following formula:

`=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(substring,text))`

'substring' and 'text' can both be cells or text.

Source:https://exceljet.net/formula/cell-contains-specific-text

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler answer if you have yahoo.com in A1 and abc@yahoo.com in B1,

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(A1,B1)),FALSE,TRUE))
```